# Auto height calculation of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to calculate the `content` div height and apply it to the `wrapper` div.

I have script which does that but the problem here is, I have auto grow `text-area` inside the `content` div which increases the `text-area` and `content` height dynamically while typing inside.

How do I automatically apply the grown div height to the `wrapper` div. I want `wrapper` div also to grow along with `content` div.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content">
     <p>lorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit sifgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgtlorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit dfdfdfdfdfdfdsitlorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit sitlore
       <textarea></textarea>
     </p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bmhm19ue/1/)**

**P.S: I can not change the `position:absolute`** of the `.Content` div

Comment: Have you tried auto height for both DIV and inner div padding ?

Comment: That doesn't work coz this is `absolute` div

Answer (score 2):

Please add below lines in resize function

```
    var contentHeight = box.parents(".content").height();
    $(".wrapper").css({"min-height":contentHeight+40});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `keypress` function on the `textarea` and calculate the height as it changes

```js
var divHeight = $('.content').height(); 
$('.wrapper').css('min-height', divHeight+40+'px');
$('textarea').keypress(function(){
    var divHeight = $('.content').height();
$('.wrapper').css('min-height', divHeight+40+'px');
})

//Textarea autogrow
;(function($){    
    //pass in just the context as a $(obj) or a settings JS object
    $.fn.autogrow = function(opts) {
        var that = $(this).css({overflow: 'hidden', resize: 'none'}) //prevent scrollies
            , selector = that.selector
            , defaults = {
                context: $(document) //what to wire events to
                , animate: true //if you want the size change to animate
                , speed: 200 //speed of animation
                , fixMinHeight: true //if you don't want the box to shrink below its initial size
                , cloneClass: 'autogrowclone' //helper CSS class for clone if you need to add special rules
                , onInitialize: false //resizes the textareas when the plugin is initialized
            }
        ;
        opts = $.isPlainObject(opts) ? opts : {context: opts ? opts : $(document)};
        opts = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);
        that.each(function(i, elem){
            var min, clone;
            elem = $(elem);
            //if the element is "invisible", we get an incorrect height value
            //to get correct value, clone and append to the body. 
            if (elem.is(':visible') || parseInt(elem.css('height'), 10) > 0) {
                min = parseInt(elem.css('height'), 10) || elem.innerHeight();
            } else {
                clone = elem.clone()
                    .addClass(opts.cloneClass)
                    .val(elem.val())
                    .css({
                        position: 'absolute'
                        , visibility: 'hidden'
                        , display: 'block'
                    })
                ;
                $('body').append(clone);
                min = clone.innerHeight();
                clone.remove();
            }
            if (opts.fixMinHeight) {
                elem.data('autogrow-start-height', min); //set min height                                
            }
            elem.css('height', min);
            
            if (opts.onInitialize && elem.length) {
                resize.call(elem[0]);
            }
        });
        opts.context
            .on('keyup paste', selector, resize)
        ;
    
        function resize (e){
            var box = $(this)
                , oldHeight = box.innerHeight()
                , newHeight = this.scrollHeight
                , minHeight = box.data('autogrow-start-height') || 0
                , clone
            ;
            if (oldHeight < newHeight) { //user is typing
                this.scrollTop = 0; //try to reduce the top of the content hiding for a second
                opts.animate ? box.stop().animate({height: newHeight}, opts.speed) : box.innerHeight(newHeight);
            } else if (!e || e.which == 8 || e.which == 46 || (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 88)) { //user is deleting, backspacing, or cutting
                if (oldHeight > minHeight) { //shrink!
                    //this cloning part is not particularly necessary. however, it helps with animation
                    //since the only way to cleanly calculate where to shrink the box to is to incrementally
                    //reduce the height of the box until the $.innerHeight() and the scrollHeight differ.
                    //doing this on an exact clone to figure out the height first and then applying it to the
                    //actual box makes it look cleaner to the user
                    clone = box.clone()
                        //add clone class for extra css rules
                        .addClass(opts.cloneClass)
                        //make "invisible", remove height restriction potentially imposed by existing CSS
                        .css({position: 'absolute', zIndex:-10, height: ''}) 
                        //populate with content for consistent measuring
                        .val(box.val()) 
                    ;
                    box.after(clone); //append as close to the box as possible for best CSS matching for clone
                    do { //reduce height until they don't match
                        newHeight = clone[0].scrollHeight - 1;
                        clone.innerHeight(newHeight);
                    } while (newHeight === clone[0].scrollHeight);
                    newHeight++; //adding one back eliminates a wiggle on deletion 
                    clone.remove();
                    box.focus(); // Fix issue with Chrome losing focus from the textarea.
                    
                    //if user selects all and deletes or holds down delete til beginning
                    //user could get here and shrink whole box
                    newHeight < minHeight && (newHeight = minHeight);
                    oldHeight > newHeight && opts.animate ? box.stop().animate({height: newHeight}, opts.speed) : box.innerHeight(newHeight);
                } else { //just set to the minHeight
                    box.innerHeight(minHeight);
                }
            } 
        }
        return that;
    }
})(jQuery);
$('textarea').autogrow({onInitialize: true});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  background:#f90;
  position:relative;
  height:auto;
    margin:10px
}
.content{
  background:#DCFFC8;
   margin:10px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0
}

textarea { margin: 1em; outline: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content">
     <p>lorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit sifgfgfgfgfgfgfg fgfgt lorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit dfdfdfdfdfdfdsitlorem ipsum elit sitloreit sitlorem ipsum elit sifgfgfgfgfgfgfg fgfgt lorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit dfddipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit dfdfdfdfdfdfdsitlorem ipsum elit sitloreit sitlorem ipsum elit sifgfgfgfgfgfgfg f dfdfdfdfdfdfdsitlorem ipsum elit sitloreit sitlorem ipsum elit sifgfgfgfgfgfgfg fgfgt lorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit dfdfdfdfdfdfdsitlorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit sitlorem ipsum elit sitlore </p>
      
     <div><textarea></textarea></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Cool. Seems like it works. thank you. BUt the problem here is when you remove the ccontent inside textarea the parent height should be decreased accordingly which is not happening.

Comment: @Sowmya You are welcome . You might also want to use a `change()` function so that it will work when copy pasted

Comment: Sorry I still dint get it. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: @Sowmya When you are typing you can see that the height automatically changes but try copy-pasting a long text then the height won't change so you might want to add `.change()` function

Comment: `.wrapper` is retaining the expanded height even after textarea content is reduced. That is because of the first 2 line of code where it is forcing `wrapper` to take the height of the `content` div.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bmhm19ue/2/)**

add a `padding` of `10px` to your `.content` class like `padding:10px`.
and then use your `autogrow` function for both `.wrapper` and `.content` as below:

```
$('.content').autogrow({onInitialize:true});
$('.wrapper').autogrow({onInitialize:true});
```

Comment: When the content of textare is removed it is not reducing the height of the div/