# Adjust parent div height according to child absolute div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well this question is sequel of my **[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30206493/1033200)** in which I could get the answer partly.

I need to calculate the `content` div height and apply it to the `wrapper` div on the basis of textarea auto expanding.

Now expanding the main div is working but `wrapper` div height is not reducing accordingly when I remove the content of `textarea/content` div. That is because by default I am calculating height of `content` div but not resetting it. below lines does that

```
var divHeight = $('.content').height(); 
$('.wrapper').css('min-height', divHeight+40+'px');
```

How do I make it auto resize the height of `wrapper` div.

**[DEMO Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mnawkgqL/)**

Answer (score 1):

- One solution is not to use a `position:absolute` element.

So your main problem is that your .content is set to `position:absolute`.
Due to that absolute positioning you need to retrieve the changed height dynamically in order to apply it to the parent DIV.

- The other solution:

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mnawkgqL/12/)***

```js
var $content  = $('.content'), // Cache your selectors for a better performance
    $wrapper  = $('.wrapper'),
    $textarea = $("textarea");

function setContentHeight() {
    $wrapper.css('min-height', $content.height() + 40 );
}

$textarea.on("input change", function() { 
    $(this).height(1).height( this.scrollHeight ); // manipulate textarea height
    setContentHeight();
}).change();                                       // Trigger

// When do we need to reflect .content height?
setContentHeight();                                // Immediately
$(window).on("resize", setContentHeight);          // and on win resize
```

```css
.wrapper{
  background:#f90;
  position:relative;
}
.content{
  background:#DCFFC8;
  margin:10px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding:10px;
}
textarea{
  outline:none;
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      lorem ipsum...
    </p>
    <div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback to the `.animate` function of the plugin and execute the resize from there. (Also remove the resize code from `.kepress` event)

```
box.stop().animate({
    height: newHeight
}, opts.speed,
function () {
    var divHeight = $('.content').height();
    $('.wrapper').css('min-height', divHeight + 40 + 'px');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mnawkgqL/10/

Comment: This works only if u delete the textarea content by suing backspace (one by one) but it wont work when you select all and delete at one shot.

Comment: Have a look at the updated post with a working fiddle. Hope that helps

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan My bad forgot to update the extra animate, check now http://jsfiddle.net/mnawkgqL/8/

Comment: A bit sloppy but nice!

Comment: Yep, Its a plugin though, not really expecting me to refactor that are you :p

Answer (score -1):

Change CSS file your problem is resolved

```
.wrapper{
  background:#f90;

}
.content{
  background:#DCFFC8;
   margin:10px;

  top:0; left:0; padding:10px
}

textarea { outline: none; }
```

View it : https://jsfiddle.net/mnawkgqL/9/embedded/result/

Comment: it has to be `position:absolute`. Otherwise removing `absolute` your answer is no better than the already provided answers.